# ini4j API - read all keys of section and create a map of it

Tags: java, ini4j

I'm new to `ini4j` API http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ini4j/ini4j. I have a requirement where if pass `key` as `CT` then it should check all `section` and populate key value pair in `Java Map`(like 10=CT,11=CT etc). How we can do this?

Cities are not fixed, it could be many cities. I've only shown 4 here.

My widget.ini

```
[CapeTown] 
10=CT
11=CT
12=CT
13=JO
14=JO
15=CT
17=WN

[Wonderers] 
21=CT
22=JO
23=WN
24=JO
25=CT
26=CT
27=CT

[Johanbege]
30=CT
31=CT
32=JO
33=JO
34=CT
35=CT
36=WN

[Durban]
40=CT
41=CT
42=JO
43=JO
44=CT
45=CT
46=WN
```

The code I started:

```
public class CityReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFileFormatException, IOException {
        File file = new File("src/main/resources/widget.ini");
        Ini ini = new Ini(file);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I developed something for you. Hope this will solve your problem.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.ini4j.Ini;
import org.ini4j.InvalidFileFormatException;
import org.ini4j.Profile.Section;

public class CityReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFileFormatException, IOException {
        Map<String, String> mapCT = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Map<String, String> mapJO = new HashMap<String, String>();

        File file = new File("src/main/resources/widget.ini");
        Ini ini = new Ini(file);
        for (String sectionName: ini.keySet()) {
            Section section = ini.get(sectionName);
            for (String optionKey: section.keySet()) {
                if(section.get(optionKey).equals("CT"))
                    mapCT.put(optionKey, section.get(optionKey));
                if(section.get(optionKey).equals("JO"))
                    mapJO.put(optionKey, section.get(optionKey));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(mapCT);
        System.out.println(mapJO);
    }
}
```

If you wanted to do something dynamic, then use below:

```
public class CityReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFileFormatException, IOException {
        File file = new File("src/main/resources/widget.ini");
        Ini ini = new Ini(file);

        Map<String, String> mapkey = new HashMap<String, String>();

        List<String> key = new ArrayList<String>();
        key.add("CT");
        key.add("JO");

        for (String s : key) {
            for (String sectionName: ini.keySet()) {
                Section section = ini.get(sectionName);
                for (String optionKey: section.keySet()) {
                    if(section.get(optionKey).equals(s))
                        mapkey.put(optionKey, section.get(optionKey));
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(mapkey);
    }
}
```